# Passing string values from list to datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to write a method who takes a xml.config file from some location in file system via Load button, parse it and after that do work with specific strings in  element attributes type and mapTo, getting some substrings from those attributes. The problem is that instead of getting strings in table I get some lines. Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Button and method call looks like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            fDialog.Title = "Open XML file";
            fDialog.Filter = "XML files|*.config";
            fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

            bool? control = fDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (control.Value)
            {
                var filePath = fDialog.FileName;
                ReadAdvancedConfigFile(filePath);
            }

        }
```

Method that gets values from xml file, take substring for each  attribute type and mapTo, put them into two separated lists and try to write content of list into a datagrid looks like this:

```
private void ReadAdvancedConfigFile(string path)
{
    XElement root = null;
    root = XElement.Load(new XmlTextReader(path));

    if (root != null)
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity";
        var registers = root.Element(ns + "unity").Element(ns + "container").Descendants(ns + "register");

        if (registers.Count() > 0)
            {
            var tipList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value);
            var mapToList = registers.Select(x => x.Attribute("mapTo").Value);
            List<string> listresult = new List<string>();
            List<string> listresultm = new List<string>();

                foreach (string tpl in tipList)
                {
                    int end = tpl.IndexOf(',');
                    int start = tpl.LastIndexOf('.', (end == -1 ? tpl.Length - 1 : end)) + 1;
                    string result = tpl.Substring(start, (end == -1 ? tpl.Length : end) - start);
                    listresult.Add(result);
                }
                foreach (string mpl in mapToList)
                {
                    int endm = mpl.IndexOf(',');
                    int startm = mpl.LastIndexOf('.', (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length - 1 : endm)) + 1;
                    string resultm = mpl.Substring(startm, (endm == -1 ? mpl.Length : endm) - startm);
                    listresultm.Add(resultm);
                }

                int maxLenList = Math.Max(listresult.Count, listresultm.Count);
                for (int i = 0; i < maxLenList; i++)
                {
                    if (i < listresult.Count && i < listresultm.Count)
                    {
                        _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresult[i], listresultm[i]));
                    }
                    else if (i >= listresult.Count)
                    {
                        _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(string.Empty, listresultm[i]));
                    }
                    else if (i >= listresultm.Count)
                    {
                        _obsCollection.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(listresultm[i], string.Empty));
                    }
                }
            tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

Content of XML.config file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
    </configSections>

    <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

        <container name="container">

            <register name="configService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.IConfigService, Web.Common"
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.ConfigServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
                <constructor>
                    <param name="res" value="Resources.ClientStrings"> </param>
                    <param name="configFile" value="webclient.config"> </param>
                </constructor>
                <!--<property name="LocalisationService" dependencyName="LocalisationService" />-->
                <!--This is a property injection from the language plugin -->
            </register>

            <register name="scaleCoefConfigService" type="Web.WebClient.Services.IScaleCoefConfigService, Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp"
                      mapTo="Web.WebClient.Services.Implementations.ScaleCoefConfigServiceImpl, Web.WebClient.TDMSWebApp">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
                <constructor>
                    <param name="configService">
                        <dependency name="configService"/>
                    </param>
                </constructor>
            </register>

            <register name="sessionService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.ISessionService, Web.Common" 
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.SessionServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>

            <register name="licenseManagerService" type="Web.Common.Interfaces.ILicenseManagementService, Web.Common"
                      mapTo="Web.Common.Services.LicenseManagementServiceImpl, Web.Common">
                <lifetime type="singleton" />
            </register>
        </container>
    </unity>
</configuration>
```

And this is how I've created Tuple for string pair. In this class is also definition for ReadAdvancedConfigFile method and Load button, of course:

```
    public partial class CreateAreaDialogWindow : System.Windows.Window
        {
            ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>> _obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>();

            public CreateAreaDialogWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
}
```

XAML code for datagrid is this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="146" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,275,0,0" Name="tabela" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" />
```

Hope I didn't get this too complicated.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem. It isn't all clear to me.

Comment: @PatrickHofman screenshot of datagrid with lines? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Won't send a picture for some reason... I will continue to try. But it's a basically Window with that one Load button and DataGrid bellow it. In DataGrid I have lines instead of strings in two columns. I think that problem may be with this line: tabela.ItemsSource = _obsCollection;
Cause I'm not sure can ItemsSource can work like that?

Comment: I got it. I saw the issue myself, but it was easier to tell with an image. Don't worry about it any more. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and you provided no columns.

Try this and it works:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Or see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to create columns.

Comment: I love u man! :D It worked! :) Thanks a lot. I know that this been stupid, but I'm still learning and that can be tough :)

Comment: And thanks for the link. I will need it :) Cause next I have to research how to add checkboxes into that tabel for each value :)